# "Trying to load a data file" and object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, statistics, economics

[enter image description here][1]

I am trying to upload a file and see the statistics, but somehow cannot
Please help me

[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here][3]

Comment: `ls()` and look at your objects. You've got a 'data file' that has the same name as a function ('the closure') complained about. Rename one or the other, probably the data, unless you wrote the function. And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: You have to assign it to an object:      `test <- cor(urate, urate_1)` and then call the object's summary: `summary(test)`

Comment: @bloxx I didnt get any numeric value
I only shows Min Median Max...etc

Comment: can you upload your data, or at least first few lines: run `dput(head(data))` and upload the output as code in your question

Comment: @bloxx I have added the questions and data

Comment: No, you didn't. You uploaded images. Do you want us to rewrite the dataset by hand?

Comment: @bloxx  Sorry, I am totally new here, so I didnt know how to upload it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here it goes. You have NA in your dataset. look at this solution:

```
cor(urate, urate_1, use="complete.obs")
```

This will only take observation with numbers and skip NAs.

Comment: ahh! thats why!! thank you!!!